# Why do I get 1 as an answer when I got (j>1) as a condition?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double rand_double() {
    return ( ((double)rand())/ ((double)RAND_MAX) );
}

int main(){
    double i=rand_double();
    double j;
    do {
        i=(i*0.5);
        j=(1+i);
        printf("%lf\n", j);
    }
    while(j>1);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's not an issue though since `j` is being set before it's ever being read.

Comment: What surprises you about the final number being `1`? `1 > 1` is false, so the loop stops.

Comment: As hinted at in the other comment, `1.0000000000001` is greater than `1`.

Comment: @Aplet123 Oops, I had read that as `j=(1+j)`.

Comment: The format for `double` is `"%f"`. If you use `"%lf"`, the `l` is ignored (so it's harmless), but I don't think that was the case in earlier versions of the language. (`long double` uses `"%Lf"`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson you're correct, `%lf` has undefined behaviour in C89.

Comment: If you want to see a variable sequence of pseudo-randoms, then try calling `srand()` once before calling `rand()`.

Comment: @ryyker And find out *how* to call `srand()`. One common method is `srand(time(NULL))`. Even so, do not rely on `rand()` to give you high quality random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are not showing enough decimal places.

So `1.000000` was output where, for example, the value is `1.00000000000000022` which is `> 1`.

Please try with more decimal places:

```
printf("%.17lf\n", j);
```

The default number of places is typically 6. The `double` type is good for about 16-17 significant digits. Revised program output:

```
1.00062562944425792
1.00031281472212896
1.00015640736106448
1.00007820368053224
1.00003910184026612
1.00001955092013306
1.00000977546006653
1.00000488773003338
1.00000244386501658
1.00000122193250829
1.00000061096625426
1.00000030548312702
1.00000015274156362
1.00000007637078170
1.00000003818539085
1.00000001909269542
1.00000000954634771
1.00000000477317386
1.00000000238658693
1.00000000119329346
1.00000000059664673
1.00000000029832337
1.00000000014916179
1.00000000007458079
1.00000000003729039
1.00000000001864531
1.00000000000932254
1.00000000000466138
1.00000000000233058
1.00000000000116529
1.00000000000058265
1.00000000000029132
1.00000000000014566
1.00000000000007283
1.00000000000003642
1.00000000000001821
1.00000000000000910
1.00000000000000466
1.00000000000000222
1.00000000000000111
1.00000000000000067
1.00000000000000022
1.00000000000000022
1.00000000000000000
```